# Repeating path query on reified data

Tags: sparql, rdf

I don't think its possible to do what I am asking using regular sparql path queries. I will ask here though in case someone has a great suggestion for me that I haven't tried.

So we have reified geosparql sfWithin and sfContains statements in a linkset. They look like this:

```
_:b1 rdf:subject :featureA1 ;
     rdf:predicate geo:sfWithin ;
     rdf:object :featureB301 .

_:b2 rdf:subject :featureB301 ;
     rdf:predicate geo:sfContains ;
     rdf:object :featureA1 .

_:b3 rdf:subject :featureB301 ;
     rdf:predicate geo:sfWithin ;
     rdf:object :featureC99 .

_:b4 rdf:subject :featureC99 ;
     rdf:predicate geo:sfContains ;
     rdf:object :featureB301 .

_:b5 rdf:subject :featureC99 ;
     rdf:predicate geo:sfWithin ;
     rdf:object :featureD4000 .
```

There are millions of these in our linkset, within a named graph in our larger graph.

I want to get something like "What are all the features that feature A1 is within?"

In a normal (non-reified) set of statements, we can do:

```
:featureA1 geo:sfWithin+ ?f .
```

I've tested that and it works as expected on a de-reified copy of the linkset, I get expected results of:

```
?f
--
:featureB301
:featureC99
:featureD4000
```

But I want to do a similar repeating path query on the original reified statements.

The closest I've got it something like this:

```
<http://example.org/featureA1> (^rdf:subject / rdf:object)+ ?f  .
```

But that follows the sfContains statements as well as the sfWithins. I need *just* the sfWithin chain.

Attempting to fix I think I need to do something like this:

```
<http://example.org/featureA1> (^rdf:subject / rdf:predicate / ?p / ^rdf:predicate / rdf:object)+ ?f  .
FILTER ( ?p = geo:sfWithin) .
```

But that doesn't work because you can't capture and compare a variable within a sparql path.

Comment: `select * {
:featureA1 (^rdf:subject / rdf:object)+ ?o .
?o ^rdf:object/rdf:predicate geo:sfWithin}`

Comment: But I don't think this would avoid intermediate nodes via `geo:sfContains` - that is impossible given that the important information is the object of a triple. In your example there is no such  case, but I'm sure once you add such in intermediate `geo:sfContains` leading to another `geo:sfWithin` my query would fail.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks for your suggestions. I tried that out on our graph, and for some reason it was returning over a million identical results, and taking 10+ minutes to run.
And you're right, if there was an intermediate sfContains (which there absolutely could be, with our dataset) then it would return false-matches.